# displaying user info for android facebook integration

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate FB in my android app ( first integration ). 
I am able to successfully login and log out.
But I am **unable** to display information after logging in.
I have tried setting the text of a  textView display for user name in onSuccess () of FacebookCallback.Also I have used correct permissions as Array.list(...).Along with onCurrentProfileChanged() of ProfileTracker, which is written in onCreate() of the fragment containing the FB login button.

Plz help.

Comment: I believe facebook has an API that could help you integrate your app with facebook. I suggest you have a look at the API to see if it can help you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm

Answer (score 0):

I won't mark this as 'duplicate', but there has been a lot of people who have asked 'very' similar questions.

You'll need to provide more detailed information, including logcat logs/stack traces of what "doesn't work" when you try it. etc. If you want more detailed help.

Here is a list of previous questions (sorted by most votes). This might help you also. 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=android%20facebook%20integration